# Running titan rexster server bat file through java

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, titan, rexster

I am trying to run rexster.bat file through a java code but the server is not coming up.

Here is my code:

```
File dir = new File("C:\\output\\titan-rexster-server-2.5.0\\bin");
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c rexster.bat --start", null, dir);
```

If i directly execute 
"rexster.bat --start "
in command prompt it works fine.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code and now its working

```
File dir = new File(destDirectory+"\\titan-rexster-server-2.5.0\\bin");
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c start rexster.bat -s", null, dir);
```